# Javascript Version

Tags: javascript, version, release

Well, i really don't know if i can ask this here but. Well my question is, if someone know about the new version of JavaScript, i've seen that the estable version is the 1.8.5 so if someone knows about the upcoming version and what's new, please tell me. Thank's

Comment: just google for history of javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John Resig answers this very nicely; [Versions of JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/versions-of-javascript/)